# How can i get the size of a disk and save it in a variable to delete it in diskpart ? CMD

Tags: windows, command-line, bash, usb, cmd.exe

i have following problem:
I would like to intercept the size of a hard drive in WinPe-Live and then delete it in Diskpart or not. Since it happens when the hard drive in the computer is defective, the USB stick deletes itself with the WinPe-Live system. To prevent this, I would like to make a query that asks the size of the hard drive or USB stick in order to format it or not to format it.

Hope you can help me with a code snippet or another solution to prevent the stick from deleting itself.

Comment: Welcome to Super User. By "CMD/BASH" do you mean "cmd *or* Bash"? Or do you mean a [batch file](https://superuser.com/tags/batch-file/info)? i.e. `.bat` which has nothing to do with Bash. Note Super User is not a script writing service. What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? Please do not respond in comments; [edit] the question and improve it.

Comment: What does "delete a drive" even mean

Comment: @TomYan with delete i mean the process in diskpart with: select disk, clean

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski i mean cmd, i tried to get the size of a disk to save it in a variable with that i want to make a "chose" or "if" something like that to say to clean the drive or not. I want to prevent to clean the usb-stick. I only want to clean all partitions, disk of the PC.

Comment: @freeprogramming `DiskPart` doesn't support variables AFAIK, but PowerShell likely can do what you want